# Retrieve and display corresponding data from firebase when clicking on spinner item in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an application that pulls all the information about a lake when selected. I have a lake database in firebase with all the important information like name, location, hours, fish found, etc. I have populated a spinner with the names of all the lakes. Now I want to click on a specific lake name from the spinner to get all of the information displayed below the spinner, I have done a ton of research but nothing helps.

This is the code I have so far

```
public class places_to_fish extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
List<String> names;
String selectedName;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_to_fish);
    names = new ArrayList<>();


    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child("Places").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                String spinnerName = childSnap.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                names.add(spinnerName);
            }
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(places_to_fish.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
                arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        selectedName = arrayAdapter.getItem(i);




                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }


    });

    





}
```

}

[Click to see Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fQ8s.png)

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

create class Lake.java

```
    public class Lake {
    public String Fish, Hours, Location, Name, Zipcode ;

    public Lake(){}
    public Lake(String Fish, String Hours,String Location, String Name, String Zipcode){
        this.Fish = Fish;
        this.Hours = Hours;
        this.Location = Location;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Zipcode = Zipcode;
    }
}
```

then, in your current class declare a HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Lake> map = new HashMap<String, Lake>();
```

now, initialize the map and add all the lakes into it

```
map.clear();
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Iterator <DataSnapshot> it = snapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext() ){
                    DataSnapshot item = it.next();
                    name = item.child("full_name").getValue().toString().trim();
                    String Fish = item.child("Fish").getValue().toString().trim();
                    String Hours = item.child("Hours").getValue().toString().trim();
                    String Location = item.child("Location").getValue().toString().trim();
                    String Name = item.child("Name").getValue().toString().trim();
                    String Zipcode = item.child("Zipcode").getValue().toString().trim();
                    Lake tmp_Lake = new Lake(Fish,Hours,Location,Name,Zipcode);
                    map.put(Name,tmp_Lake);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

now you have a map with all the lakes info (sorted by their names)
so now, when you choose lake, you can take all the details from the map.
this code will create array "names" with the lake names

```
public void addToList(){
        String [] names = new String[map.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(User tmp : map.values()){
            names[i] = tmp.Name;
            i++;
        }
```

call this method after you initialize the map
and finally, displaying the selected lake info by creating a string and load it to a textbox

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter(place_to_fish.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
            String lake_name = names[i];
            Lake tmp = map.get(names[i]);
            String [] Lake_details = new String[5];
            Lake_details[0] = "Name: "+tmp.Name + "\n";
            Lake_details[1] = "Fish: "+tmp.Fish + "\n";
            Lake_details[2] = "Location: "+tmp.Location + "\n";
            Lake_details[3] = "Hours: "+tmp.Hours + "\n";
            Lake_details[4] = "Zipcode "+tmp.Zipcode + "\n";
            String text = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < Lake_details.length; i++)
                text += Lake_details[i];
            full_text.setText(text);//"full_text" is a clear text box
        }
    });
```